# Find $z$ if $dz=\frac{y dx- x dy}{3x^2-2xy+3y^2}$

Tags: calculus

How can we find $z$ if $$dz=\frac{y dx- x dy}{3x^2-2xy+3y^2}$$

I have no idea how to start, appreciate your help :)

Comment: Hi, there   divide numerator and denominator by $y^2$. Then you have $dz=\frac{du}{3u^2-2u+3}$ where $u=\frac{x}{y}$ .Hence you have a simple integration

Answer (score 1):

$$dz=\frac{y dx- x dy}{3x^2-2xy+3y^2}$$
$$
\begin{align}
 z &=\int \frac{y dx}{3x^2-2xy+3y^2} - \int\frac{x dy}{3x^2-2xy+3y^2}\\&=
\int \frac{y dx}{3 (x - y)^2 + 4 x y } - \int\frac{x dy}{3 (x - y)^2 + 4 x y }\\&=
%\frac{1}y\int \frac{ dx}{3 (x/y - 1)^2 + 4 x/y  } - \frac{1}x\int\frac{ dy}{3 %(1 - y/x)^2 + 4  y/x }\\&=
%\int \frac{ du}{3 (u - 1)^2 + 4 u  } - \int\frac{ du}{3 (1 - u)^2 + 4  u }\\&=
\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2}}
\left( \arctan \left( \frac{3 x-y}{2 \sqrt{2} y} \right) - 
{\arctan\left(\frac{3 y-x}{2 \sqrt{2} x}\right)}\right)=
\arctan\frac{2 \sqrt{2} \left(y^2-x^2\right)}{x^2-6 x y+y^2}
\end{align}
$$
using $\arctan x\pm \arctan y=\arctan\frac{x\pm y}{1\mp xy}$